# "Google Chrome" disappears from "Browse With.." list in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: google-chrome, visual-web-developer

After I add "Google Chrome" using "Browse With.." in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, it dissappears from the list of browsers almost right away, although browsers like Firefox remain in the list. I was thinking that it might be due to the default installation location of Google Chrome in Windows, anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a bug report to Microsoft and they fixed the problem for me.
Here is the [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693937/google-chrome-does-not-remain-in-the-list-of-browsers-when-using-browse-with).